# Very simple question about logical operator in C lang

Tags: c, logical-operators

I have a question about C lang. There are logical operators in C like `&` and  `|`.
I used it in this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%d",(1>2)||(2==2);
    printf("%d",(1>2)|(2==2);
}
```

I know why the printed value is 1,  but I don't know why the compilers didn't get errored.

Are there no problems that the number of logical operators is one or two?
(eg: ||, | get the same value)

Are there any rules about the number of logical operators that use in print functions?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I assume you do **not** know whyt you get the outptu you get. You mess up logical operators and bitwise operators. You might revisit your favorite C tutorial or textbook and look up these basics.

Comment: `&` and `|` are bitwise operators, and quite different from the logical operators `&&` and `||`.  Also, the parentheses in the code you posted are unbalanced, which is why it won't compile, so presumably you aren't using the code you posted.

Answer (score 2):

You did not specify the error the compiler raises but each `printf` command is missing an enclosing bracket:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%d",(1>2)||(2==2));
    printf("%d",(1>2)|(2==2));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C, `x | y` performs an individual logical “or” operation on each bit of `x` with the corresponding bit of `y`, while `x || y` performs a logical “or” operation on the whole value: the result is zero if both values are zero and one if either `x` or `y` is non-zero.

For example, if the bits of `x` are 0110 0111 and the bits of `y` are 0011 0001, then the bits of `x | y` are 0111 0111, and `x || y` is 1.

In your code, `1>2` produces the value 0, and `2==2` produces the value 1. For these values, `0 | 1` produces 1 (because the bits are 00…00 ORed with 00…01, which produces 00…01, which is 1) and `0 || 1` produces 1 (because one of the operands is non-zero, so `0 || 1` produces 1).

This is unrelated to whether they are used in a `printf` call or elsewhere.